# Laminas acl navigation with multiple roles

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-acl, laminas

I have question about laminas navigation and acl.
In my application, a user can have multiple roles non hierarchicals. But in the documentation, I have read that only one role should be passed to it via setAcl('myacl')->setRole('roleUder').
Because my users can have cumulative roles, how to apply them on navigation?

Answer (score 0):

More information in regards to your roles would be very helpful. You can only pass one role to the navigation helper.

If role A + role B grants privilege X

Then role B inherits from role A. Role B gets passed to the navigation helper.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).